# Why is start menu button not showing up?

Tags: 11.04, troubleshooting, 11.10

why ubuntu start button not showing up in ubuntu 11.10; While upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 it throwed me upgrade not successful, but i'm able to login as 11.10, now that i see there is no ubuntu start button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Start" button is on the left side, the first button on the launcher.
[image: 11.10 Launcher Panel Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the "Ubuntu start button" has moved in 11.10 from the top menu to the panel - the panel is displayed when you move mouse cursor to the left edge of the screen.

See this for more details: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/08/revamped-dash-lands-unity-2d/

There is a chance, however, that you mean something completely different :)